# How would I validate my Scrolling List with my current code?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a function that will validate if an option is selected in my Scrolling List. If nothing is selected, and alert will go off, if one is selected, then it passes validation. This is the code I am using:

```
<select id="topList" name="toppings" size="8" multiple>
                               <option value="opCream">Whipped Cream</option>
                               <option value="opFudge">Hot Fudge</option>
                               <option value="opMarsh">Marshmallow</option>
                               <option value="opCherry">Cherries</option>
                               <option value="opChocSprinkles">Chocolate Sprinkles</option>
                               <option value="opRainSprinkles">Rainbow Sprinkles</option>
                               <option value="opCheese">Cheesecake</option>
                               <option value="opOreo">Oreo Crumbles</option>
                           </select>

function checkScrollList() {
                    var ddl = document.getElementById("topList");
                    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (selectedValue == false)
                    {
                        alert("Please select a sundae topping.");
                    }
                }
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`selectedIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) of the `select` object, like this:

```
function checkScrollList() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("topList");
    if (ddl.selectedIndex === -1) {
         alert("Please select a sundae topping.");
    }
}
```

The `selectedIndex` property will give the zero-based index of the *first* selected option, so it is not useful for actually retrieving all the selected options. But it is guaranteed to be `-1` when no options are selected.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Going to have to take note of this. Thanks for the help!